# iOS - SKNavigationSettings Audio advices, no difference between transportMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

Here is what i tried:

```
[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].navigationDelegate = self;
SKNavigationSettings* navSettings = [SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings];
navSettings.transportMode = SKTransportPedestrian;
navSettings.showStreetNamePopUpsOnRoute = YES;
navSettings.viaPointNotificationDistance = 5;
navSettings.navigationType=SKNavigationTypeReal;
navSettings.distanceFormat=SKDistanceFormatMetric;
[[SKRoutingService sharedInstance]startNavigationWithSettings:navSettings];
```

I dont find any differences in the behavior when i tried different transportMode. What i believe is Audio advices are only targeted for Car, where advices are alerting user before large distances (take right turn in 30 meters....). But i want it to alert user in short distances (take right turn in 2 meters ...)

What can i do to get advices which are for pedestrians but not for Car/bike riders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the pre-defined distances for pedestrian advices in SKMaps.bundle > AdvisorConfigs > Pedestrian> advice_places.adv
Where the first column represents distances_outside_city and the second distances_in city.
[Here](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-scout-audio/) you can find more info and know how on the SDK audio advices.